# Assume $| \int gf |\leq M||f||_p$ for all simple $f \in L^p$. Prove that $g \in L^q$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This statement is proved in Royden. However, I was wondering if it is possible to show that this is a bounded linear functional, which then by Riesz would imply that $g \in L^q$. Is this approach possible? If so, can it be extended to work for any dense set of $L^p$?

What I tried is let $f \in L^p$ then take a sequence of simple functions such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise and in $L^p$. Now we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\int f_ng|\leq M||f||$. I am not sure how to proceed from here to show that $\int fg <\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are working in a  sigma finite measure space.

$Tf=\int fg$ defines  a bounded linear functional on the space of simple functions which is dense in $L^{p}$.  Hence it extends uniquely to a bounded linear functional on the whole of $L^{p}$. So if you assume that the dual of $L^{p}$ is $L^{q}$ the we can write $\int fg=\int fh$ for all simple functions where $h$ is in $L^{q}$. This implies that $g=h$ a.e. so $g \in L^{q}$.

Theorem

Let $T$ be a continuous linear functional on a dense linear subspace $V$ of  a normed linear space $X$. Then there exist a unique continuous linear functional $S$ on $X$ such that $Tx=Sx$ for all $x \in V$.

Proof: let $x \in X$. There is  a sequence $(x_n) \subset V$ such that $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$. Now $\|Tx_n-Tx_m|| \leq \|T\| \|x_n-x_m\| \to 0$ so $(Tx_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of scalars. Hence $\lim Tx_n$ exists. Call this $Sx$. It can be verified easily that this limit does not depend on the particular sequence $(x_n)$ so $S$ is well defined. It is elementary to verify that $S$ is linear. Finally $\|Sx\| =\lim \|Sx_n\|=\lim \|Tx_n\|\leq \|T\| \|x\|$ so $S$ is bounded. Uniqueness of the extension is also elementary.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but how do I extend it without knowing $g \in L^q$

Comment: I am not using any property of $g$. Any continuous linear functional on dense subspace extends uniquely to a continuous linear functional on the whole space. For this you don't need any formula for $Tf$. @Sorfosh

Comment: Could you refer me to a theorem? Since this is not a continuous linear functional on $L^p$,but on a subspace of $L^p$. If what you say is true then the proof is indeed trivial.

Comment: @Sorfosh This is an elementary result. I have now included a proof of it in my answer.